# How to automatically link title and URL in BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls, href

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically link a title and URL in BibTeX such that the title becomes a hyperlink to the webpage.

Currently, my bibliography entries look like this:

```
@article{
    Author2000,
    author = "Author, Albert A.",
    title = "\href{https://www.mypaper.org}{A Very Inconsequential Paper}",
    journal = "Journal of Inconsequential Results",
    volume = "12",
    pages = "34--56",
    year = "2000",
}
```

As you can see, I am currently achieving the desired effect using `\href{}{}` in the title field. However, I would like to have a bibliography entry like this:

```
@article{
    Author2000,
    author = "Author, Albert A.",
    title = "A Very Inconsequential Paper",
    journal = "Journal of Inconsequential Results",
    volume = "12",
    pages = "34--56",
    year = "2000",
    url = "https://www.mypaper.org",
}
```

That is, an entry that does not use `\href{}{}`, but instead uses a url field or something similar. Is it possible to achieve the same effect in this way ideally using just LaTeX and BibTeX?